# Snapchat Lens-like feature for IOS

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, google-vision, vision

i am searching a tutorial or helps about to create a snapchat lens-like feature in iOS with swift or objective-C either with Google Mobile Vision or IOS Vision framework.
I want to achieve something like android's do : 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/523-augmented-reality-in-android-with-google-s-face-api
if you could help me or suggest me an open source library that has this ability.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is not the correct place for asking suggestions. This is for programming questions.

Comment: It’s programming suggestions are welcome but i have implemented the vision sdk yo detect the face landmarks and i have converted them to uiview points (x,y) coordinates but now my problem is to scale my objects to match the distance between my camera and the user face also handle rotation and another big problem is that my points vibrate and do not stay in place